# Django error when annotating with StringAgg plus another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-3.2

I'm trying to get a flat list of site names associated with each user. The results will be written to a CSV file:

```
email,sites
a@b.com,site1|site2|site3
b@b.com,site3
```

StringAgg works to flatten `sites` in an annotation. Both `has_flag` and `is_admin` work in an annotation. All of these fields work with `created_date`. But if I try to include `sites` with either `has_flag` or `is_admin`, it throws the error `'WhenNode' object has no attribute 'copy'`.

Simplified code:

```py
users = (
    account.get_users()
    .annotate(
        is_admin=ExpressionWrapper(Q(role=1), output_field=BooleanField()),
        has_flag=ExpressionWrapper(Q(thing__isnull=False), output_field=BooleanField(),
        created_date=Func(F("created_at"),Value("YYYY-MM-DD"),function="to_char", output_field=CharField()),
        sites=StringAgg('usersite__site__name', delimiter="|"),
    )
    .values_list(
        "email",
        "is_admin",
        "has_thing",
        "created_date",
        "sites",
    )
)

class UserSite():
    class Meta(object):
        unique_together = ("user", "site")

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Why do you use ExpressionWrapper?

Comment: Good question. It should add a `copy` method [from the BaseExpression class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ed0cc52dc3b0dfebba8a38c12b6157a007309900/django/db/models/expressions.py#L346), and at some point when I added `ExpressionWrapper` I was able to get a different error... but unfortunately I haven't been able to reproduce that. With the current code, ExpressionWrapper has no effect.

Comment: Thanks, your question made me question why the ExpressionWrapper had no effect, and it turns out the error may involve a different field. Updated my question.